# Computing CDF expressions

Tags: probability

Let X be a discrete random variable with the density function P(X=x)=x/z, that is defined when x∈{1,2,...,20}, and z is a normalization constant. Let F(X) be the CDF of X. What are the values of the following expressions?

What is F(5) =  1/z ( ? )

What is F(20) = 1/z ( ? )

Can someone please help me with these two. A little confused on these expressions

Comment: What is $\large\mbox{CDF}\ ?$.

Comment: Cumulative distribution function

Comment: Thanks. There are a lot of acronyms in this place.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You can find the normalization constant $z$ by solving 
$$
1=\sum_{x=1}^{20} P(X=x)=\sum_{x=1}^{20}\frac{x}{z}.
$$

To find e.g. $F(5)$, you simply have to recall the definition of a CDF:
$$
F(y):=P(X\leq y)=\sum_{x: x\leq y} P(X=x).
$$
For instance,
$$
F(5)=\sum_{x=1}^5 P(X=x).
$$